# Where can I see the source code for classes within my current ruby intallation?

Tags: ruby, load-path

I am new to ruby but nonetheless I have installed various versions of Ruby using RVM,
Here's the the output of my LOAD_PATH

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > puts $LOAD_PATH
/home/jose/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/home/jose/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
/home/jose/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/home/jose/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/home/jose/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
/home/jose/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/home/jose/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1
/home/jose/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
```

Ok. So the question here is, Where within these directories can I see the source code for classes like Array, or Time ? (I know, it's an extremely n00b question, but I need to know.)

I've been needing to take a look at the source of Array for a long time.

Thanks in advance!

PS. Which class do you recommend looking at if I want to become a better ruby programmer?

Comment: Looking at the source for those classes won't help you be a better ruby programmer, since they are partially written in C.  You could instead look through SO for book recommendations for ruby programing. Grab the pickaxe book, look at the api for the ruby standard library...

Comment: "look at the api for the ruby standard library" That's exactly what I want to look at. Can you provide a link please?

Comment: seriously?  try going to google and typing: ruby api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coolest gadget for code browsing I found so far is `pry`:
http://pry.github.com/

It's an `irb` replacement with a lot of goodies. An example session so you can see how you can browse code with it (and you'll also see that it can show the C-implementation of a class):

```
> pry
pry(main)> show-
show-command  show-doc      show-input    show-method   show-source
pry(main)> show-source Array

From: object.c in Ruby Core (C Method):
Number of lines: 6

static VALUE
rb_f_array(obj, arg)
    VALUE obj, arg;
{
    return rb_Array(arg);
}
pry(main)> cd Array
pry(Array):1> show-source each

From: array.c in Ruby Core (C Method):
Number of lines: 12

VALUE
rb_ary_each(ary)
    VALUE ary;
{
    long i;

    RETURN_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0);
    for (i=0; i<RARRAY(ary)->len; i++) {
    rb_yield(RARRAY(ary)->ptr[i]);
    }
    return ary;
}
pry(Array):1>
```

Pry can of course also list the Ruby source of classes.

Another useful tool for browsing the C-source for Ruby is the Ruby code cross reference:
http://rxr.whitequark.org/

However right now it seems to be down, but hopefully it will be up again soon.

Comment: Cool, this is pretty much what I was looking for. Now, Is there a way to output the location of the file which I'm viewing? That'd be really excellent.

Comment: @user - Pry will show the full path to Ruby source. For C-code it seems to just show the plain file name, but you can easily find that by downloading the Ruby source code package yourself from ruby-lang.org.

Comment: hey, pry can actually only show the source of methods - the source of an entire class (especially a C class) would be enormous, going into 1000s of lines of code and not much use. Instead pick the method you're interested in for a class and Pry will show the source for that.

Answer (score 0):

Array is partially implemented in C for performance reasons, so for Array you would need to download the Ruby source code.

Comment: That might change over time.  You can currently browse it here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby.  Check the official website at http://www.ruby-lang.org/ if the previous link doesn't work.